# sustituir elementos en listas anidadas en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero sustituir elementos en listas de listas para dibujar una cruz.
Así por ejemplo la lista:

```
x="X"
lista =[[x," "," "," ",x],[" ",x," ",x, " "],[" "," ",x," "," "],[" ",x," 
",x, " "],[x," "," "," ",x]]
for l in lista:
        print (" ".join(l))
```

resulta en :

```
X       X
  X   X  
    X    
  X   X  
X       X
```

Pero no consigo sustituir correctamente los `items` en una lista de orden "`size`", como se muestra en el siguiente código:

```
size =int(input("Which is the size of the nested lists? "))
col=[]
for x in range (size):
    col .append(str(x))
tablero =[]
for b in range(size):
    tablero.append(col)

for row in range(len(tablero)):
    for col in range(len(tablero)):
        if col == row:
            tablero[col][row]= "X"     
for l in tablero:
    print (" ".join(l))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu caso podrías intentar algo así para evitar esos ciclos anidados:

```
size =int(input("Which is the size of the nested lists? "))

tablero = []
for i in range(size):
    row = [" "] * size // crea una lista de tamaño size
    row[i] = "X" // agrega "X" en la posición i 
    row[size - i - 1] = "X" // agrega "X" en la posición (size - i - 1)
    tablero.append(row)
```

La idea es crear primero el tablero vacío y luego ir agregando las filas. En cada fila seleccionas la posición la cual deseas editar.

Answer (score 1):

Hola mi solución es la siguiente:

```
n = 10

# matrix de n*n
m = [ [' ' for y in range(n)] for x in range(n)]

for i,r in enumerate(m):
    m[i][i] = 'x'
    m[i][n-i-1] = 'x'
for r in m:
    print(''.join(r))
```